# How to merge two arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following arrays which I'd like to combine / merge to create a single array that I can loop through to add images and their respective titles to a database.

**Array 1:**

```
[0] => array(1) {
  ["filename"] => string(22) "1463668615_1_image.jpg"
}
[1] => array(1) {
  ["filename"] => string(22) "1463668641_1_image.jpg"
}
```

**Array 2:**

```
[0] => array(1) {
  ["title"] => string(15) "My image title"
}
[1] => array(1) {
  ["title"] => string(5) "Title"
}
```

Here's the format of the array I'd like to create.

**Merged Arrays:**

```
[0] => array(2) {
  ["filename"] => string(22) "1463668615_1_image.jpg",
  ["title"] => string(3) "My image title"
}
[1] => array(2) {
  ["filename"] => string(22) "1463668641_1_image.jpg",
  ["title"] => string(0) "Title"
}
```

Comment: What? Why do the titles end up as "MFH" and an empty string?

Comment: Have you even googled this? First result - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: @Styphon And you'd expect that to work on multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: @JonStirling Yes, I would. If you read the documentation it says it does.

Comment: @Styphon And if you read the documentation, you will find that it doesn't do what OP is asking.

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Comment: @JonStirling - Sorry. The titles in my merged arrays snippet were wrong. I've corrected them now.

Comment: @Styphon Thanks for your input - I tried that and couldn't get it to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_merge()` is the way just use it as the callback in `array_map()`:

```
$result = array_map('array_merge', $array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly this called **zip**, not **merge**. You can do this with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function:

```
$filenames = [
    ['filename' => '1463668615_1_image.jpg'],
    ['filename' => '1463668641_1_image.jpg']
];

$titles = [
    ['title' => 'Title1'],
    ['title' => 'Title2']
];

$zipped = array_map(function ($elem1, $elem2) {
    return [
        'filename' => $elem1['filename'],
        'title' => $elem2['title']
    ];
}, $filenames, $titles);

var_dump($zipped);
```

Here is [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/55dc1598985c9f45bd015de329568c0e0492230b).

Answer (score 1):

Will the structure of the arrays be the same? And will the size of those arrays also always be the same? If not, there is no sure way to do this, if yes, you can do a simple loop:

```
$arr1 = array(
    0 => array(
        "filename" => "1463668615_1_image.jpg",
    ),
    1 => array(
        "filename" => "1463668641_1_image.jpg",
    ),
);

$arr2 = array(
    0 => array(
        "title" => "My image title",
    ),
    1 => array(
        "title" => "Title",
    ),
);

$new = array();
for ($k = 0, $size = count($arr1); $k < $size; $k++) {
    $new[$k]['filename'] = $arr1[$k]['filename'];
    $new[$k]['title'] = $arr2[$k]['title'];
}

var_dump($new);
```

Comment: @Daninis Put the count outside the loop, it's an unnecessary overhead!

Comment: I declined your edit, since it was not, what I intended to show. You can check the manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: yes either way will do, I prefer to set the variable explicitly outside the loop because it's more readable but my 'Wait for it...' point was you are comparing `$i` not `$k` you rebel!

Comment: @DainisAbols I would hope you test your own code. Its your answer not mine.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

**PHP**

```
    $filenames = [["filename" => "1463668615_1_image.jpg"], ["filename" => "146366865213_image.jpg"]];
    $titles = [["title" => "Titre1"], ["title" => "Titre22"]];

    foreach ($filenames as $key => &$value) {
         $value['title'] = $titles[$key]['title'];
    }

    var_dump($filenames);
```